# How can play video in jsp page which is fetched from oracle database

Tags: jsp, servlets

```html
 <p>   I am able to fetch the video from database in jsp page but it is showing like address. So how to play it in jsp page.
thanks in advance
In jsp page 
--------------------
Serial Number Description Videos
3 hbjghvfg "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@25e6fd4d"
4 hghhcs oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@6fac1d5e
5 inserted video for testing oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@1f6b4371
6 fddfdf oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@2211ef76
7 vbvbv oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@442a0e49
8 hhbvb oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@6514448
9 dfdgg oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@6e50c12b
21 grhrh oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@7a01ff1d
22 bnbhbn oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@eb35ba0
26 ghfjh oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream@79f7991b
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have stored Java objects in your Oracle database. You will have to select the blobs and de-serialize them into a local object, and embed it into the resulting page.

(also, you might want to add the Oracle tag to your question to expand it)

Something like:

```
<%
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select videos from your_table")
rs.next();
InputStream istr = rs.getBlob("videos").getBinaryStream();
Object obj = new ObjectInputStream(istr).readObject();
String strObjClass = obj.getClass().getName();
out.println("Retrieved object " + obj + " of the class " + strObjClass);
%>
```